# heidisql - one window per database

Tags: heidisql

I've been using HeidiSQL version 3.2 for a number of years and just moved to 7.0.

Is there any option that will force a different heidisql window for each different database? currently it is all brought together under one window - for me, personally this is dangerous for running scripts on the wrong database.

Any suggestions would be useful.
Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

Start a new session from a new session manager window instead of an existing session. If you start from an existing session then the sessions are combined.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure about running queries on the wrong server, you can give each session its own tree background color. Just log into your session, then click `File > Select session background color` to chose a color. This helps you distinguishing between your sessions.

Apart from that, HeidiSQL dims the database tree text color of non-focused sessions slightly, so the focused session appears in black color (depending on your Windows color settings), while other opened sessions appear in grey.

Beyond that, HeidiSQL automatically detects unsafe UPDATE and DELETE queries without a WHERE clause, and warns you with a confirmation dialog before actually executing such query in a `Query` tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you're worried about running scripts on the wrong database, is to create a read-only account on each DB. Then only specifically connect with a write-enabled account when you need to run queries.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if right now everything is put together in one window this is not a problem. Every time it will run a query, just click on the database in question, and it will activate or at least be different from other databases. This doesn't seem like too much effort.